# How to report the results of an anova() model comparison?

Tags: r, anova, reporting

I have two models with the same outcome variable and the same independent variables, but `Model 1` has two more independent variables than `Model 2`. I do an `anova()` test in R to check whether these two variables are important. According to the output they are.

```
  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1  60914 1629530                                  
2  60916 1636407 -2   -6877.2 128.54 < 2.2e-16 ***
```

How do I have to present these results in an academic paper? I'd prefer mentioning it within the text, rather than adding an entire table.

Is something like this ok: F(60,916, 60,914) = 128.54, p < 0.001? I've seen some sources use this for anova tests which compare a [variable across groups.](http://statistics-help-for-students.com/How_do_I_report_a_1_way_between_subjects_ANOVA_in_APA_style.htm#.YDjCpGhKhPY)

Comment: Charlotte, it depends on publication norm you use. For example, I use APA norms (American Psychological Association) and they recommend to report anova in this format: F(2, 60914) = 128.54, p < .001. Note that first degrees of freedom are the difference of d.f. between your model and its submodel.

Comment: Thank you @DanielDostal, I also use APA so this solves my question!

Comment: Follow up question: Why is it F(2, 60914), and not F(2, 60916)?

Comment: @DanielDostal Your comment looks like an answer.  I'm trying to reduce the number of unanswered questions.  Could you post it as an answer?